# How to get a HTML element in a HTML element array with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code that gives me all the `LABEL` inside the HTML element with id "nuovaImmagine":

```
$.labelImmagine = $("#nuovaImmagine1").find("label");
```

I know that inside `$.labelImmagine` there are 3 labels. If I do `alert($.labelImmagine.size());` the alert shows "3";

Now I have to get the first element of the array and edit the text of the label.

I tried both `$.labelImmagine.get(0).text("Hello")` and `$.labelImmagine[0].text("Hello")` but none works.

Any idea?

Thank you

Comment: `$.labelImmagine.eq(zeroBasedIndex).text('Hello World!')`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** and change its text with **[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**

```
$.labelImmagine = $("#nuovaImmagine1").find("label");
$.labelImmagine.eq(0).text('some text');
```

Check the **below snippet**

```js
$.labelImmagine = $("#nuovaImmagine1").find("label");
$.labelImmagine.eq(0).text('some text')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nuovaImmagine1">

  <label>label 1</label>
  <br>
  <label>label 2</label>
  <br>
  <label>label 3</label>
  <br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want the HTML element, you want the jQuery object of that HTML element. I can tell because you're trying to use jQuery methods on it.

Both `$().get(0)` and `$()[0]` give you DOM nodes. **You need** `$().eq(0)` or `$().first()`, which return a jQuery object.

Answer (score 1):

It's  a **bad idea** to pollute the `$` namespace.  I'd rather use

```
var $labelImmagine = $("#nuovaImmagine1").find("label");
//   ^--- no dot.
```

But yea.... otherwise, simply do like

```js
$.labelImmagine = $("#nuovaImmagine1").find("label");
$.labelImmagine.eq(0).text("WOOOOO");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nuovaImmagine1"><label>TEST</label></div>
```

and all wrapped inside an IIFE or document ready scope:

```
jQuery(function($) { // DOM ready and $ alias secured
    /**/
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to continue using Jquery you would need to re-'jqueryify' the element.
For example

```
$($.labelImmagine[0]).text("Hello")
```

This is because by selecting the element by index it is no longer a jquery object, and thus .text() doesn't exist.

Otherwise you could use

```
$.labelImmagine[0].innerHTML = "Hello"
```

Comment: It's works. I didn't give you the downvote, it wasn't me

Comment: Sorry - I wasn't implying it was you! I was asking in general if I needed to expand on something.